# When publishing from VS 2012 to an Azure Website my Entity Framework seed data is not inserted in SQL Azure

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Entity Framework 5.0 and Code First.

I have published my website using Visual Studio 2012 to Azure Website.  Everything seems to work except that the seed data is not inserted into SQL Azure; the website works, the database is built, but the seed data is **not** inserted.  When I run this on my local machine, everything works correctly.

Based on examples that I have seen, when publishing from Visual Studio 2012 there is an option called “Execute Code First Migration” (see image below).

[image]

But when I try to publish my website the option “Execute Code First Migration” is **not** available.
[image]

I believe this may have something to do with how my solution is configured. I have 3 projects that makes up my application.

- **Website** – This is an ASP.NET MVC project.  It does have a reference Entity Framework, but all data access code (DBContext) is in the Data project
- **Domain** – This is a class library.  It does not have a reference to Entity Framework
- **Data** – This project has reference to Entity Framework.  I have a Configuration class that inherits from DbMigrationsConfiguration.  In
  this Configuration class I override the Seed method.

Again this all works on my local pc.  For the most part everything works on Azure; the web site works, the database get built, but the seed data is not inserted.

For my scenario, are there any recommendations how to get the seed data to insert into SQL Azure when I do a publish from Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: You may need to define the Entity Framework context in the web.config file.

Instructions can be found [here](http://www.ralphlavelle.net/2012/09/entity-framework-code-first-webconfig.html) in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually edit your pubxml file (Properties/PublishingProfiles/YourName.pubxml) to make the check box appear. I have a blog post describing the situation and solution here: http://www.dominicstpierre.net/2012/11/enable-code-first-migrations-check-box.html

This part need to be manually changed

```
<PublishDatabaseSettings>
  <Objects xmlns="">
    <ObjectGroup Name="Namespace.Models.YourDBClass" Order="1" Enabled="True">
      <Destination Path="your-connection-string-goes-here" />
      <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
        <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="Namespace.Models.YourDBClass, AssamblyName" MigrationConfiguration="Namespace.Migrations.Configuration, Assambly" Origin="Convention" />
      </Object>
    </ObjectGroup>
  </Objects>
</PublishDatabaseSettings>
```

Change Namespace.Models.YourDBClass by your class that inherits DbContext, change Namespace.Migratins.Configuration to fit your migration configuration namespace and Assambly with your Assambly name.

Save and open the publish wizard you will have that check box.